# Moodle upgrade from 2.1 to 2.2 causes intermittent 304s for js files

Tags: upgrade, moodle

After upgrading from Moodle 2.1 to 2.2 I'm experiencing a very strange issue.

Firefox appears to work consistently.

Both Safari and Chrome work inconsistently, and each exhibits several failure modes.

All failure modes consist of one or more console errors (the error message varies) in conjunction with none of the Navigation items responding to clicks, except for straight links.  For instance, "Settings" and "Front Page Settings" are collapsable nav items; these do not work.

There's one particular resource which Safari stubbornly wants to cache.  I've disabled Safari's cache via the develop menu and emptied the cache, and still requests for /theme/yui_combo.php + query params (as well as, intermittently, other js files) returns a HTTP 304 (Not Modified).  As far as I can tell, it's not the code doing this; I modified the header() call in that file to show a custom message and I got the usual Not Modified one.

Firefox also gets the 304s, but doesn't appear to be adversely impacted.  In Chrome/Safari, I've only managed to get it to work when all HTTP responses are 200, leading me to believe that some outdated version(s) of the file(s) are cached and causing the error.

I found https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=202508 which seems to describe a similar issue and tried the solutions there, but so far nothing has worked.

Any suggestions?  I'm a Moodle noob, so I may well have missed something obvious.

Thanks in advance!

Josh

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered upgrading to a supported version of Moodle? Moodle 2.2 general support ended 2 years ago, with security fixes ending 18 months ago.

The latest version (2.8.1, at the time of writing), may not have the issues you describe (you could always install it on a test server, with a copy of your database and try it out).

Comment: That was the original plan, actually.  We were going to go as far as 2.7.x (which is the latest supported by our client's host's version of PHP).  The same issue appeared when I went through the whole process and upgraded all the way to 2.7 (on our test server).  Since 2.2 was an interim step (you can't upgrade directly from 2.1 to 2.7) I started the process fresh and only went up to 2.2 to see which version introduced the problem.

Comment: Could you try a couple of things - 1. purge all caches (Site admin > Developer > Purge all caches), 2. (if that doesn't help) set $CFG->jsrev = -1; in config.php (this should turn off the javascript caching, but will make the site slower as a result - should only be tried as a temporary measure).